# Check to see if any customers have purchased all items, if all items purchased, reset column data to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query help needed.

I need to check and see if a customer has purchased all items in a list, if they've purchased all of them, I want to reset timesPurchased column back to zero for only that customer. Table looks like this

```
customerId   | productId    | timesPurchased 
-------------------------------------------------------
A            | 000000001    | 1
A            | 000000002    | 1
A            | 000000003    | 0
B            | 000000001    | 1
B            | 000000002    | 1
B            | 000000003    | 3
```

In this example only customer B has purchased all three of the items so I would like to reset only customer B, timesPurchased column back to zero.

The logic is, find customers who have purchased all the items, then reset the timesPurchased counter back to zero.

Comment: Should all 3 timesPirchased related to (customerId, productId) be reset to 0 or only one of them? What do you want your result set to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM TableName t1
    WHERE t.customerId= t1.customerId   
    AND   t1.timesPurchased = 0
)
```

So for the update:

```
UPDATE t SET timesPurchased = 0
FROM TableName t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM TableName t1
    WHERE t.customerId= t1.customerId   
    AND   t1.timesPurchased = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set timesPurchased = 0
where customerId in
(
  select customerId
  from your_table
  group by customerid
  having count(distinct productId) = (select count(distinct productId) from your_table) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already some answers, but this ones a bit different, so I'll throw it on the pile:

```
UPDATE <table> 
SET timesPurchased = 0
WHERE customerID IN
    (
        SELECT customerID
        FROM <table>
        WHERE
            sum(CASE WHEN timesPurchased > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = count(productID)
        GROUP by customerID
    )
```

This will test that the sum of timesPurchased is equal to the count of productIDs in the table. If they are equal then the subquery returns the customer. If the customer is returned to the main query, then it sets it's timesPurchased to 0 for all records for that customer.